# Extract data from the second level link, scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

There is a web site with the links to another web-pages. I would like to do the following:

1. Go to the each link on the page
2. Extract all text between `<p></p>` tags

For this, I wrote the following parser:

```
 def start_requests(self):
    date=" "
    for url in self.urls:
        yield Request(url=url,meta={'date':str(url)[-15:-5]},callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')
    passed_date=response.meta.get('date')
    items=[]
    for site in sites:
        item = DmozItem()
        # item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = str(site.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()).replace("u'","")
        item['link']=item['link'].replace("'","")
        # item['time'] = site.xpath('.//div/text()').extract()
        # item['date'] = passed_date
        self.all_articles.append(item)
        item['text']=[Request(url=link_of_the_article,callback=self.get_text_of_the_article) for link_of_the_article in item['link'].split(',')]
    return items

def get_text_of_the_article(self,response):
    sel=Selector(response)
    article_text=""
    item=DmozItem()
    item['text']=sel.xpath('//*[@id="articleText"]/p[1]').extract()
    return items.append(item)
```

However, when I print the `item['text']` the result is:

```
{[<GET %20http://www.domain.com/article/2014/01/06/libya-economy-idUSL6N0KD2L320140106%5D>]}
```

How can I get the text between the specific tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see:

```
{[<GET %20http://www.domain.com/article/2014/01/06/libya-economy-idUSL6N0KD2L320140106%5D>]}
```

is because you are saving the `Request` object in `item['link']` instead of yielding it.

This is what you should be doing. Explanation in the comments in-line.

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')
    passed_date=response.meta.get('date')
    items=[]
    for site in sites:
        item = DmozItem()
        # No need to replace u'. It is an internal representation for unicode
        # strings. It won't affect your data
        links = site.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
        self.all_articles.append(item)
        # For all the links, yield a Request and send the 
        # item object
        for link in links:
            yield Request(url=link, callback=self.get_text_of_the_article, meta={'item': item})


def get_text_of_the_article(self,response):
    sel=Selector(response)
    # Get the item object sent from parse method
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    # You can save the link url here
    item['link'] = response.url
    item['text'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="articleText"]/p[1]').extract()
    return item
```